# How do I show a.e. equal randome variables generate the same sigma algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a measure space and $X,Y$ be almost everywhere defined $\mathscr{F}$-measurable real functions.

Then, how do I show that $\sigma\{X^{-1}(A):A\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\}= \sigma\{Y^{-1}(A):A\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\}$?

If this is not true, then can one at least prove that if a real function is measurable with respect to $\sigma\{X^{-1}(A):A\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\}$, then it is measurable with respect to $\sigma\{Y^{-1}(A):A\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true. It's *almost true*, that is, in a sense true up to sets of probability zero.

But say the probability space is $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure for the probability. Define $X=1$,  $Y=\Bbb 1_{(0,1]}$. Then $\sigma(X)$ contains only two sets, while $\sigma(Y)$ has four elements.